# Emacs shell: command history lost after restart

Tags: shell, emacs

A very useful time-saver for working with shell is that you can search for command history using Ctrl - r. Emacs has the same functionality in its shell mode: C-S-r. However, the shell's history is cleared every time emacs is restarted. Any idea how to persist the history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general the answer would be:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `savehist` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Enable `savehist-mode` and configure the variables you wish to persist between sessions.

However in this case I think you'll find that it's your shell which is tracking its command history; not Emacs.

e.g. for bash, commands are stored in `$HISTFILE` (by default `~/.bash_history`), but depending on your settings, the history from one shell may be clobbered by another shell, depending on which one exits last. For bash, read the `HISTORY` section of its man page.

**Edit:** For `comint-mode` and derivatives (including `shell-mode`) the *searchable* history is read in via `comint-read-input-ring`, which uses `comint-input-ring-file-name` which you can set in a mode hook. However I would suggest that you actually set your `HISTFILE` environment variable to `~/.zsh_history` because shell-mode automatically defers to that.

It seems a little odd to me that zsh doesn't already do this, mind (assuming you're starting Emacs from a zsh shell?). If you use some kind of GUI launcher, OTOH, the environment Emacs starts in may not be what you want? I couldn't say for sure.

Failing that, the documentation suggests that this ought to work:

```el
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-hook)
(defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
  (setq comint-input-ring-file-name "~/.zsh_history")
  (comint-read-input-ring t))
```

(but using `HISTFILE` would be better).

n.b. I'm using Emacs 24.3 and the keybindings are different to those you have described (`M-r` to search the history in shell-mode; `C-S-r` is unbound for me), so YMMV. I always run my shells inside `ansi-term`, so I couldn't tell you whether this functionality has changed recently.

Comment: I got the mini-buffer history working. However, the shell history is still missing from Emacs. I'm using zsh, so should I set Emacs to point to ~/.zsh_history? Where can I do that?